# Django - Relationship Model

Tags: django, django-models

I need some help for database relationship and assignment.

For instance, we have an employee model

```
class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
         email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, unique=True)
         employee_no = models.IntegerField()
         first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
         last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
         middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 
         def __str__(self):
             return str(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
```

And let say an employee can have a group of task. But before that, we have to create a task in order to group it.

This is a task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
         id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         task_code = models.CharField(max_length=150, 
                                     unique=True, editable=False)
         name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
         type = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
         description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

         def __str__(self):
             return self.name
```

We then now group the tasks.

```
class GroupTask(models.Model):
         id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
         group_code = models.CharField(max_length=150,
                                      unique=True, editable=False)
         task = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)
 
         def __str__(self):
             return self.name
```

So after grouping, we now have a list of task in group task model. For example, in Group 1, we have Task 1, and Task 2.

This group of task should also be in a project, so we have to connect this group of task in a project model. Because each projects should have a group of task.

```
class Project(models.Model):
        code = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False, 
                               default=auto_generated_code)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        group_task = models.ManyToManyField(GroupTask, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```

We are now able to add a grouptask in a project. But at this moment, we have not assign any group of task to an employee. So we have to create a separate model for that.

```
class TaskAssignment(models.Model):
        employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        group_task = models.ManyToManyField(GroupTask)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.employee.last_name + ', ' + self.employee.first_name
```

So my question now is, since we are assigning a grouptask to an employee, how can i determine what project this grouptask is in?

For example, i assign Group 1 to ‘Employee Test’.

And this ‘Group 1’ is in a Project 1, and Project 2, because each ‘GroupTask’ can be use to multiple projects.

But i only want to assign Group 1 in Project 1, how can i do this? Because at this moment, i am only assigning grouptask to an employee, but i don’t know yet how can i determine what project this grouptask is in.

Thank you!

Comment: do you want a a task to be in many taskgroups?

Comment: and is there more than one employee assigned to a single grouptask? I think you are using manytomany in a few places here where you want to be using a ForeignKey. I'll post an answer as what I think you may want.

Comment: Yes you are correct! Task can be use in multiple taskgroups. And for the second question, Correct as well, each grouptask can also assigned to many employee.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my first pass for what I think you may want, although it is still unclear as to what some of your desired relationships are. In general, I think you have more many to many fields than you need. For your task assignment, do you really want to assign a group of tasks to potentially more than one employee or do you want to assign an employee per task (and a task happens to be a member of a GroupTask for categorization purposes?).

To make your later queries easier, using the `through='TaskAssignment'` argument on the employees in GroupTask (or group_tasks in Employee if you prefer, depends on how you thinnk about it) would be helpful

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    employee_no = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)


class GroupTask(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    group_code = models.CharField(max_length=150,
                                  unique=True, editable=False)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(through="TaskAssignment")
    # task = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_task = models.ForeignKey(GroupTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_code = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False, default=auto_generated_code)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    group_task = models.ForeignKey(GroupTask, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class TaskAssignment(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_task = models.ForeignKey(GroupTask)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee.last_name + ', ' + self.employee.first_name
```

Comment: Yes bro, i really need to assign group of task to more than one employee, and the task are really a member of group task for categorization purposes.